# Problem with compilation for maven project

Tags: scala, maven, compilation

I have two maven projects - a library and a small program. They are in  different folders and use different `pom.xml` and the library's jar files are included in the small program's `pom.xml` using the following plugin:

```
<groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

and an absolute path:

```
<resource><directory>/path/to/jars</directory></resource>
```

This worked correctly, but then suddenly with same code as before in both projects, the small program does not compile anymore. The library still compiles fine.
(Using `mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`)

The error message is not very clear:

```
[ERROR] error: error while loading <root>, error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
...
[ERROR] error: fatal error: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.935s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 15 22:39:11 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/67M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.0:compile (default) on project testprogram: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

I did some researches on Google about the error message and it seems that this can be caused by a missing or damaged .jar file. I do not see the relation to this case tho, because I had the same code and imports in both the working and the not working case.

EDIT: to add some more information: the library is using [junixsocket](http://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/) and is including the .jar in the same way as the program includes the library. It seems that the problem appears only when this part is there.

Comment: Just general tips:

- Ensure the parent project has the Scala runtime libraries available (not only the subproject)
- Considere to use SBT (it usually handles the Scala runtime and other libraries better that Maven when developing Scala code)

Comment: maybe you run into a problem of your IDE - close the first project and retry the build. Also you can really delete the files in your .m2 folders to be sure...

Comment: Is the jar file ok now?  Can it be unzipped correctly?  (It may have been mangered by git or non-binary file transfers or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Two key helpers in sorting out what maven is doing and why it is doing it are:

mvn help:effective-pom - this generates a pom file with all properties resolved and all tasks described - this includes the default ones

mvn -X - debug maven execution will generate a lot of information.

I usually, direct mvn -X to a text file and then go hunting for the keywords around the errors.   tI use the effective pom to help me figure out how it gets the values.

Path problems are usually the problem in this kind of problem if this is case of can't find the necessaries.

Answer (score 0):

Open a zip file during maven compilation could be thrown because the maven compiler pliugin tries to explode a jar for exposing in classpath during compilation. If so you can check if your .m2/repository is corrupted.

Another check you can do is to read in the pom if there is a plugin that points to a specific folder for your compilation that provide specific libraries, so restore the library in the folder should solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by java version > 8, try it with java 8.